# Change-of-basis without using orthogonal as new basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I have a question in my exam which is:

> Let :v = [3,1] and *T* : R2 -> R2 denote the transformation such that
> T(x) is the vector in span{v} nearest to x
>
> Let :0<a<pi/2 denote the angle between the positive x-axis and the
> vector v. Let *R*: R2->R2 denote the transformation such that R(x) is
> the vector x rotated by the angle a ***clockwise***
>
> Find the Linear transformation R and T ***(Dot product and Differentiation is not allowed)***

I know that R is just a clockwise matrix, but for T, the answer says it is found by producing an orthogonal vector w=[-1,3] to form a new basis and then produce a change-of-basis matrix P =
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3 & -1  \\
1 & 3  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then since T(x) is in span(v), so the transformation performed on the new basis = B =
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Then by T=PB(P^-1) we can find out the answer A =
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0.9 & 0.3 \\
0.3 & 0.1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

But I have 2 questions neither the professor nor TA answer me

> 1. What if I choose any other arbitrary vector to form the new basis instead of using the orthogonal one? says w=[0,3]
>
> I did some try before asking, but the answer is wrong. I guess that happened on the Matrix B transformation performed on a new basis, probably because the basis is no longer orthogonal. But isn't the *T* simply project x on v when the basis is changed? which means no height and any other vectores, so the matrix shouldn't be same????

> 2. TA says there is actually another easier method, he just hint us T(x) = [ ? ? ]
>
> I am extremely confused with this so-called easier form, I referred to David Lay, linear algebra Ch5.4, I guess he wanted to say is the transformation form x -> Ax, which can be calculated by putting a basis in the transformation and attaining a new basis vector, then form a new transformation matrix. Is that the so-called easier form? How does it work??

Really sorry for my ignorance and bothering your time